# .htaccess "stuck" in xammp - Mac OSX

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

I have a number of local sites set up with XAMMP.  They all work fine except one.  They all have identical configuration in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName aheadlocal
DocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Sites/aheadlocal/"
 <Directory "/Users/myname/Sites/aheadlocal/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All
</Directory>
```

While downloading the latest version from the dev server, I accidentally downloaded an .htaccess file that was redirecting certain directories to the live site.

I deleted the .htaccess file, flushed DNS, stopped and restarted Apache and even shut down and rebooted my computer.

Yet I am still being redirected, just on certain directories.  There are no other .htaccess files in those directories and no other redirects in the files.  I even have caching turned off in httpd.conf

This is not drupal or wordpress - I'm not using a database.  It's just php/javascript and Foundation 4.

I'm stumped.  Any ideas?

Comment: Clear your browser cache!

Comment: @anubhava Redirection headers are not cached.

Comment: If `R=301` has been used then it is definitely cached in browsers.

Comment: Of course I cleared my browser cache.  I actually have caching turned off in my php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to MAMP and that fixed the problem.